# Why does Deja Dup appear to be backing up unchanged files?

Tags: 14.04, backup, deja-dup

Yesterday I ran an initial backup of my home folder and an additional storage folder using Déjà Dup in preparation for an upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS.  This backup took well over 12hrs to complete, and as this was the first backup, I expected it to take some time to complete.

This morning I created a couple of extra text files and ran another backup expecting it to complete fairly quickly.  However Deja Dup completed the initial scan and proceeded to back up hundreds, if not thousands of files, including some rather large dormant untouched virtual machine images. (This is based on the "Details" output during the backup stating that it is "Backing up:" the files in question)

My understanding is that only new or changed files would be backed up incrementally as required.  Admittedly the second backup appears to be progressing somewhat quicker but it is still taking quite some time considering very few changes that would have occurred since the last backup.

Additional info that may, or may not, be relevant is that I am backing up from both encrypted (home) and unencrypted (additional storage) locations to an encrypted external USB HDD.  On top of that, the backups are also encrypted by Déjà Dup.

Can anyone explain why this would this be happening or is this expected behaviour using Déjà Dup?  Is it actually backing up these files or just checking for changes but still stating that they are being backed up?

Update:
The second backup (incremental) finally completed in 7hrs 20min with the backup files (duplicity-inc.*) totalling 195GB.
The previous backup (full) took 15hrs 30mins and the backup files (duplicity-full.*) totalled 411GB.

The incremental backup is almost half the size of the full backup which seems excessive considering there were hardly any significant changes from when the full backup was done.  Is this to be expected?